Cannot use React 19 new `use` hook
I am trying to try out new features of React 19.
In order to do that, I have created React app with Vite and TypeScript:
npm create vite@latest

Then upgraded to React 19 libraries (accoridngly to this article):
npm install --save-exact react@rc react-dom@rc

After this I can see upgraded React version in package.json:
"dependencies": {
    "react": "19.0.0-rc-d8c90fa4-20241001",
    "react-dom": "19.0.0-rc-d8c90fa4-20241001"
}

Now I want to try out new React 19 features, one of which is new hook use, but when I try:
import { use } from 'react'

I get an error that it's not exported from react:

Module "react" has no exported member 'use'

Obviously, I did now complete correctly "migration" to React 19 - what did I miss? How to make it work?
I also have suspicion that this feature might be specific to React Server Components..

The @types/react you're using don't yet have that name, so TypeScript is confused.
You could try a local module augmentation file (e.g. src/react-19.d.ts):
/// <reference types="react" />

declare namespace React {
  export function use(): void;  // fill in with the correct signature
}


Thanks, I tried it and it partially worked - now use is found of course, but everything else imported from React is now "not found"

@MichałTurczyn Ah, derp, my bad. Fixed with the correct augmentation.

As could be read in GitHub issue

It is only available in canary channel docs

So, at page of react npm I found latest Canary version: 19.0.0-canary-cb151849e1-20240424 and I have installed it for react and react-dom.
Now, everything seems to be working with use hook, however the error remains.

Install the latest version of @types/react. If it does not fix, do this:
declare namespace React {
  export function use<T>(usable: Usable<T>): T;
}


In my case, i only install react@19, react-dom@19, @types/react@19 and @types/react-dom@19
npm i react@19 react-dom@19 @types/react@19 @types/react-dom@19

and That it's.

you actually can not use the use inside a typescript project, because the react.d.ts do not have the use member.
Go with a js project and it will work as expected.
I set up a really quick project to use React 19 if you want to React 19
